# python regex issue with underscore

Tags: python, regex

i am trying to do some string search with regular expressions, where i need to print the [a-z,A-Z,_] only if they end with " " space, but i am having some trouble if i have underscore at the end then it doesn't wait for the space and executes the command.

```
if re.search(r".*\s\D+\s", string):
    print string
```

if i keep

```
string = "abc shot0000 "
```

it works fine, i do need it to execute it only when the string ends with a space `\s`.

but if i keep

```
string = "abc shot0000 _"
```

then it doesn't wait for the space `\s` and executes the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `search` and this function, as the name says, search in your string if the pattern appear and that's the case in your two strings.

You should add a `$` to your regular expression to search for the end of string:

```
if re.search(r".*\s\D+\s$", string):
    print string
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor the RE at the end of the string with `$`:

```
if re.search(r".*\s\D+\s$", string):
    print string
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `$`:

```
>>> strs = "abc shot0000 "
>>> re.search(r"\s\w+\s$", strs)     #use \w: it'll handle A-Za-z_
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xa530100>
>>> strs = "abc shot0000 _"
>>> re.search(r"\s\w+\s$", strs)
#None
```